# Skipping a number of bytes in a ZipInputStream

Tags: java

So at the end of a ZIP file, like the last 64K there is a Central Directory from which you could see what the ZIP file it self contains.

Now I have loaded my ZIP file into a ZipInputStream and before that I have declared a long variable that is the length of the ZIP file - the 64k.

So I want to skip as many bytes and the long variable states, and only start reading info after that. But I dont really understand how the `.skip()` method works for ZipInputStream.

After using it, the `.getNextEntry()` method will still start from the beginning and `.read(byte[64 * 1024])` will tell me that it's the end of the stream which it should not be?

So what is this skip() method actually doing and how can I get my Central Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are mixing two things here.

Either read your data as a plain `InputStream`, go to the position you want and start reading and parsing the plain data yourself.

Or use the `ZipInputStream` API and iterate through the `ZipEntries`. The `ZipInputStream` is an abstraction on top of the raw stream that handles reading the central directory and uncompressing the compressed bytes transparently. So you cannot get access to the raw directory using the `ZipInputStream`.

For more information, see also

- [How does ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784102/how-does-zipinputstream-getnextentry-work)
- [How to read content of the Zipped file without extracting in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778980/how-to-read-content-of-the-zipped-file-without-extracting-in-java)

Comment: ZipInputStream has skip implemented, but getNextEntry does not read from where you skipped .